# faster search protocol with large list (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, search, vector

faster search protocol with large list?
hello and thanks for reading my post. I'm making some simple autocomplete software that compares the word being entered to every word that matches that word's sequence of letters in the English dictionary. The dictionary contains 400,000 elements so as you could expect it makes for a very long wait time for simple searches.

```
                for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++)
                {
                    if (list[j].length() >= input[input.size()-1].length() && input[input.size() - 1] == list[j].substr(0, input[input.size() - 1].length()))
                    {
                        suggestions.push_back(list[j]);
                    }
                }
```

The code above is probably the least efficient for runtime optimization, but I tried some other things like creating a displacement variable for all 27 letters and then adding that to i. and reducing the maximum to the next letter start (if the index of the first letter, say r, is 400, and the index of the first letter beginning with s is 800, then I would set the range between 400 and 800 instead of 0- 1,500 but it still was slow). Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Look into the trie data structure.

Comment: You could have an array of containers.  The array would have one slot for each letter.  The slot would have a container of all words starting with that letter.  Example `dictionary['A']` would have a container of all words starting with 'A'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort your dictionary.  Then you can binary search for the word, since you're matching prefixes only (i.e. you aren't trying to find "hello" by typing "ell").

Also this is very inefficient:

```
input[input.size() - 1] == list[j].substr(0, input[input.size() - 1].length())
```

That innocent-looking `std::string::substr()` allocates memory every time!  You can use `std::string::compare()` to do the same comparison without memory allocation, which will make this part ~10x faster.

Comment: Side note: `input[input.size() - 1]` has an unfortunate tendency to explode when `input` is empty. If this is impossible, groovy. If not, ka-boom. `input[input.size() - 1]` -> `input[0 - 1]` - > `input[-1]` -> (assuming the safe bet of 64 bit 2's compliment) `input[FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF]` which is Zounds... out of range of an empty container.

Comment: okay so thanks for tip on compare. the syntax for the parameter looks like this 
```input[input.size()-1].compare(0, input[input.size() - 1].length(),list[j],0, input[input.size() - 1].length()) == 0
```
and it appears to be faster. But how would you do a binary search with the sorted dictionary? Should I compare the ascii value of first letter of the word in input[input.size()-1] with the ascii value of the word in dictionary, and if it doesn't match half the index?

Comment: @Abdumuminkhan: to do binary search, use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound